# creation of fiducial symbols in allegro

Tags: pcb-design

1.what is proper design rules to create fiducial symbols?
2.How to create fiducial symbols in allegro,and what layers should i give ?

Comment: Why are you asking how to create them if you don't know what they're needed for? What have you managed to learn about them so far?

Comment: Very late to the party, but, the OP's wording doesn't make me think they don't know the point of fiducials. Allegro is _picky_ about how you set up fiducials. There are TONS of available layers to choose from, and it's not immediately clear which one is needed. I came here looking for the same advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no specific experience with Allegro but to answer in general terms.

1. Fiducial marks are usually placed on any side of the board which has machine placed components particularly Surface mount.
2. They are read by a placement to confirm the exact size and placement of the copper layer.  In practice PCB artworks may be slightly stretched or shrunk and not perfectly aligned.  The error is not so big as to stop the board being used but may be enough for a component to be misplaced without them.  They are typically placed in 3 corners of the PCB.  And you may require local fiducials around fine pitched components.
3. Yes they are still used and are becoming more important as surface mount components get smaller.
4. Check with your manufacturing house.  Typically I use a 6mm dia hole in the solder resist with a 1.5mm circular pad in the centre.  It is important that these are clearly visible until all machine placed components are placed but they can be covered when placing hand fitted components.  Also ensure none of the fiducial is covered by silk screen.

Comment: are u using pad designer to create this symbols\

Comment: Not an Allegro user so can't comment on a particular but in Orcad for example this would be a non-electrical pad created in the pad stack editor.

Comment: thanks for your good reply waren hill,i will do that